# Bootstrap layout change in angular5/MVC

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, bootswatch

I had written as part of my app a basic Menu which went horizontal across the top of the page and was in my _Layout.cshtml file. This was originally in .Net Core 1.1 with Angular 2. I'm also using a theme from Bootswatch.

I upgraded my app to .Net Core 2 and Angular 5 and also moved to Webpack. I upgraded bootstrap to version 4. Now when I run the same piece of code the menu is to the left and goes vertically. Here's my original code, what do I need to do to make this top and horizontal again.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact t</a></li>
            </ul>
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of place. I would suggest that you run the program and use Inspect to view the styling of your menu. That will help you to start pin-pointing why your menu is out of place.This is unfortunately what we have to do when we upgrade our libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,the issue is that webpack does not recognise bootswatch v4. In my Packages.json file I needed to ensure that both bootstrap and bootswatch were at version 3.3.7. Then in the non-shakable tree values in the webpacks config file I just needed to make a reference to `bootwswatch/{theme that I want}/bootstrap.css` there is no need to download the theme from the bootswatch site.